# React native app crashes on start when add " apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' " into " /android/app/build.gradle " file

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, gradle

I am integrating firebase into my **react-native android app**. The problem is that when I add this line: **"apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'"** at top or very bottom, in gradle file at **"/android/app/build.gradle"**, my app crashes on startup.

But when I comment this line, my application starts normally.

I **rigorously** configure firebase in my application according to the official documentation.
https://rnfirebase.io/#installation

I have been looking for solutions on the internet for 2 weeks without success.

Please kindly help me.

--

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.16.1",
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^4.1.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^5.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^8.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.2.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.5.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.5.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^14.5.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/database": "^14.5.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^14.5.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/functions": "^14.5.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging": "^14.5.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/installations": "^14.5.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.5.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "^14.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
    "@sindresorhus/to-milliseconds": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "expo": "~44.0.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "i18n": "^0.14.1",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.49",
    "pretty-bytes": "^6.0.0",
    "pretty-ms": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.67.2",
    "react-native-create-thumbnail": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-date-time-scroll-picker": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.5.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-ffmpeg": "^0.5.2",
    "react-native-file-access": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.11",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.12.0",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.17.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2"
  },
```

--

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = '30.0.3'
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31

        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'

        // Google Firebase
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../android'))
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../dist'))
        }

        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }

        jcenter() {
            content {
                includeModule("com.yqritc", "android-scalablevideoview")
            }
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

--

android/app/build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"
    apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
    
    // codes
    
    dependencies {
        // codes
    
        // Firebase
        // Import the Firebase BoM
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.1')
    
        // Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
        // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth' 
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-installations'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    }

    // codes
```

Comment: did you resolve? i have the same issue and im beating my head :-|

Comment: me to bro please provide solution if you fixed